# Beam job with Repeated AfterProcessingTime trigger runs forever

Tags: python, triggers, apache-beam

I tried to create a beam pipeline that allows late events and has an `AfterProcessingTime` trigger so that the trigger can aggregate all the data that arrive in time at its first fire and fire as few times as possible for late data. I found [this tutorial](https://github.com/griscz/beam-college/blob/main/day2/B1_Beam_College_Advanced_Windows_and_Triggers_a_practical_guide_v0_9_0.ipynb), but my pipeline got stuck with their `late_data_stream`

```
options = StandardOptions(streaming=True)

with TestPipeline(options=options) as p:
  _ = (p | create_late_data_stream() 
      | beam.Map(lambda x : x) # Work around for typing issue
      | beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(5), 
                        trigger=beam.trigger.Repeatedly(beam.trigger.AfterProcessingTime(5)),
                        accumulation_mode=beam.trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
                        allowed_lateness=50)   
      | beam.combiners.Count.PerKey()
      | beam.Map(lambda x : f'Count is {x[1]}')
      | "Output Window" >> beam.ParDo(GetElementTimestamp(print_pane_info=True))
      | "Print count" >> PrettyPrint()
)
```

Any idea why is this happening? And is there a way to have repeatedly trigger to stop if the watermark goes past window_end+ allowed_lateness?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by your Beam job getting stuck? Did you get any errors?

Comment: yes, please do clarify what you mean? are you seeing that the trigger stops firing?